# Where can I find glew32.dll and glew32mx.dll files for an OpenGL GLEW project using MinGW?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, codeblocks, glew

I am learning OpenGL using GLEW-2.0.0. And I am using CodeBlocks 16.01.
I downloaded GLEW-2.0.0 .tgz archive from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.0.0/glew-2.0.0.tgz/download%5C).

Then I extracted and compiled the source files by creating a .bat file and copying the following code, which I found in the internet:

```
{   
gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o

gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.mx.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32mx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32mx.dll.a -o lib/glew32mx.dll src/glew.mx.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
ar cr lib/libglew32mx.a src/glew.mx.o

}
```

Then I copied the include files and lib files into respective directories of MinGW folder. And I linked opengl32, glu32, glew32 and glew32mx in Codeblocks after creating a project. But there are not any glew32.dll and glew32mx.dll files in any directories inside GLEW-2.0.0 folder.

When I compile an OpenGL program, it compiles without any errors but when I run it, only a console window appears and says "Press any key to continue". 
If I comment out `glewInit();` statement, the program runs fine and SDL2 creates window. But as soon as I use `glewInit();` the program compiles well but only console window appears.

I think, this is due to missing glew32.dll and glew32mx.dll files. I can't find these files even after compilation of GLEW. So, where can I find these files for my program? Or what else should I do?

EDIT: I managed to make my project work. I added glew.c file into my project and added the line "#define GLEW_STATIC" without quotes on the top of my main.cpp file. Then I compiled the project and it worked perfectly. I know this is static linking but it's fine for me.

Comment: can't you just compile it?

Comment: I compiled it but the compilation process didn't created *.dll files. But it created glew32.a, glew32mx.a, glew32.dll.a, glew32mx.dll.a files. These files aren't working. Or I don't know how to use these files.